# Set a variable in the app_controller and use it in a CakePHP layout

Tags: cakephp, controller

I need to set a variable in the app_controller of CakePHP and then use it in my default layout file.

Is there a way to set this variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what he meant was, that he doesn't know where to set a variable since he's not in a specific function inside a controller. To have a variable (or anything else really) available everywhere, you have to put it in your AppController like this:

```
function beforeFilter()
  {
  $this->set('whatever', $whatever);
  }
```

More on those callback functions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks).

Answer (score 5):

The callback functions in AppController are the place to $this->set() variables that you want available to all of your views and layouts. beforeFilter() is called before all controller actions. If you want to set a view variable after an action has run, use beforeRender(). You can access your other view variables in the $this->viewVars associative array.

```
function beforeRender() {
    $new = "Universal " . $this->viewVars['layoutTitle']; 
    $this->set('universalTitle', $new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set the variable :
$this->set(compact('currentJobId'));

It will set array at the same time it will set values to it.